# import torchでUnicodeDecodeErrorになります

Tags: python, pytorch

`import torch`をしようとすると`UnicodeDecodeError`になります。どうすればデコードできるでしょうか？

```
File "/home/haga/Context-Cluster/models/context_cluster.py", line 11, in <module>
    import torch
  File "/home/haga/yes/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/__init__.py", line 605, in <module>
    _C._initExtension(manager_path())
  File "/home/haga/yes/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py", line 125, in <module>
    _lazy_call(_check_capability)
  File "/home/haga/yes/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py", line 123, in _lazy_call
    _queued_calls.append((callable, traceback.format_stack()))
  File "/home/haga/yes/lib/python3.8/traceback.py", line 197, in format_stack
    return format_list(extract_stack(f, limit=limit))
  File "/home/haga/yes/lib/python3.8/traceback.py", line 211, in extract_stack
    stack = StackSummary.extract(walk_stack(f), limit=limit)
  File "/home/haga/yes/lib/python3.8/traceback.py", line 366, in extract
    f.line
  File "/home/haga/yes/lib/python3.8/traceback.py", line 288, in line
    self._line = linecache.getline(self.filename, self.lineno).strip()
  File "/home/haga/yes/lib/python3.8/linecache.py", line 16, in getline
    lines = getlines(filename, module_globals)
  File "/home/haga/yes/lib/python3.8/linecache.py", line 47, in getlines
    return updatecache(filename, module_globals)
  File "/home/haga/yes/lib/python3.8/linecache.py", line 137, in updatecache
    lines = fp.readlines()
  File "/home/haga/yes/lib/python3.8/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 6181: invalid start byte
```